# rabbitmq binding not work with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

with spring boot 1.5.9 RELEASE, code as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitmqConfig {
    @Autowired
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Bean//with or without this bean, neither works
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue bbbQueue() {
        return new Queue("bbb");
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange requestExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("request");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bbbBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(bbbQueue())
                .to(requestExchange())
                .with("*");
    }

}
```

After the jar stars, there is no error message and there is no topic exchange showing in RabbitMQ managementUI(15672) exchanges page.

However, with python code, topic exchange shows and the binding can be seen on exchange detaile page. python code as below

```
 connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='10.189.134.47'))
 channel = connection.channel()

 channel.exchange_declare(exchange='request', exchange_type='topic', durable=True)

 result = channel.queue_declare(queue='aaa', durable=True)
 queue_name = result.method.queue

 channel.queue_bind(exchange='aaa', routing_key='*',
                           queue=queue_name)

 print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')

 def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        print(" [x] %r" % body)

 channel.basic_consume(callback, queue=queue_name, no_ack=True)

 channel.start_consuming()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied your code and it works fine.

**NOTE** The queue/binding won't be declared until a connection is opened, such as by a listener container that reads from the queue (or sending a message with a `RabbitTemplate`).

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "bbb")
public void listen(String in) {
    System.out.println(in);
}
```

The container must have `autoStartup=true` (default).

Comment: guessed the same reason when morning shower. works fine. thanks